# How do call an SQL stored procedure from Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, ios, stored-procedures

I have an iPad app and I'm trying to call a stored procedure in a remote SQL server. Is there a library or something in the framework I can use to call a SQL stored procedure?

Comment: Have you googled for your answer?

Comment: NSResponders answer is correct.  In most cases the database vendor will have a C API.

Comment: I guess more specifically I'm looking for an Objective-C solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Karl Kraft’s Objective-C wrapper for MySQL](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2011/06/07/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx-version-2-0/#more-162)?

Answer (score 2):

You use the C API provided by the database vendor.

Comment: I guess more specifically I'm looking for an Objective-C solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a middle man to help, its simple to process a HTTP request from objective c, so what I usually do is create a PHP page on the remote server that calls a procedure (whether its login/send mail etc) then returns any information which I parse and read in the app.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm looking for a more direct way to do it in Obj-C instead of using a PHP page.